# Axis scales in the heatmap

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
Pest = gridfit(ke, ks, S.totDis, ke_pts, ks_pts);
imagesc(Pest)
colorbar;  
xlabel('k_e'); ylabel('k_s');
```

[image]

I wish that the scale of the axis be the values of data instead of the data point indexes.
This might be naive. I am new to matlab, please help.

Edit:[image]
I wish the y-axis to be increasing instead of decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick look at the [documentation of imagesc](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) indicates you that you can use the syntax `imagesc(x,y,C)` to specify `x` and `y`.

In your code, this gives:

```
Pest = gridfit(ke, ks, S.totDis, ke_pts, ks_pts);
imagesc(ke, ks, Pest)
colorbar;  
xlabel('k_e'); ylabel('k_s');
```

**Edit**

To make the y axis ascending, just use the command:

```
axis xy
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks! There is still one problem the yaxis is descending instead of ascending.Check edit. How change I can this?